# Redis: ERR Rewriting config file: Permission denied when using Docker data volume

Tags: docker, redis

I am using a redis docker container which reads its configuration file from a separate data-only container. Right now I set the redis.conf file using another container. Now I was experimenting around and I tried using the

```
> config rewrite
```

command and I get:

```
> (error) ERR Rewriting config file: Permission denied
```

I can't figure out why permission is denied. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems like the data container has set the file permissions for your .`conf` to a user that doesn't exist in another container. `ls -al` your redis.conf. is the user the one you expect it to be?

Comment: @stacksonstacks `-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         45458 Jun 29 23:32 redis.conf` is my output

Comment: What user are you running the container you're experimenting from? use `whoami`

Comment: @stacksonstacks In the redis container, the user is root. Is it something related to using redis-cli? The command i'm executing in the redis container is: `docker exec -it redis redis-cli`

Comment: @wracks did you ever get to the bottom of this? I am seeing the same thing with Redis 4.0.8 on Docker...

Answer (score 0):

I think redis will create a new temp file on the same folder as the current config file. Then replace the current config file with the temp file.

So it need a permission to write new file in the path.

For example, if your config file is `/etc/redis/redis.conf`, you have to ensure redis have write permission with `/etc/redis/` folder.

For `redis:7` docker image, you should do `docker exec -u root redis_containenr chown redis:redis /etc/redis`